# Google Hangouts logged in multiple locations

Tags: google-hangouts

If I already have a Google Hangout session active and I log into the same account from a different device at the same time what will happen?

Comment: Why not just try and see?

Comment: What do you mean by “what will happen”?

Answer (score 2):

You'll be in the Hangout on both devices.

I do this once in a while with my laptop and my Android phone to check out some new functionality.

From what I've seen, you can only be in a Hangout twice. If you try to add a third device you'll get logged out elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the hangout "chat" here's my observation:

- I had up to 4 sessions opened on 4 different devices (I didn't try to see how many I can have, it just happened). That includes Android app, website, and IM application, on multiple operating systems.
- If you are not currently typing or *active* in any of the sessions they will all notify you of message received and show the messages.
- If you are active or typing in any of the sessions, then notifications (audible) will be only on that session, but all will display the messages.
- Unless you're using a chat application, such as `pidgin`, then the receipt of messages and notifications stops as soon as you activate any other session.

This is solely based on my observation since I've been using this service on a daily basis for a few good years now.